# Queue leak of an element?

Tags: c++, templates, queue

I am writing a simple queue in C++ with a template, but my valgrind keeps saying that I am leaking:

```
==5427== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5427==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==5427==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 4 frees, 72,768 bytes allocated
==5427== 
==5427== 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==5427==    at 0x4C29110: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5427==    by 0x50E366F: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==5427==    by 0x400E8E9: call_init.part.0 (in /lib64/ld-2.19.so)
==5427==    by 0x400E9D2: _dl_init (in /lib64/ld-2.19.so)
==5427==    by 0x40011C9: ??? (in /lib64/ld-2.19.so)
==5427== 
==5427== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5427==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5427==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

And here is my implementation:

```
template <typename T> class Queue
{

    struct node_t {
        T data;
        struct node_t* next;
    };
    node_t* newNode(T data)
    {
        node_t* n = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        if (n) {
            n->data = data;
            n->next = NULL;
        }
        return n;
    }

public:

    Queue() : m_head(NULL), m_tail(NULL) {}
    ~Queue(){}

    void put(T data)
    {
        node_t* n = newNode(data);

        if (m_tail != NULL) {
            m_tail->next = n;
        }
        m_tail = n;
        if (m_head == NULL) {
            m_head = n;
        }
    }

    T get()
    {
        node_t* it = m_head;
        if (m_head != NULL) {
            m_head = m_head->next;
        }

        T ret; 
        if (it != NULL ) {            
            ret = it->data;
            free(it);
         }
        return ret;
    }

    bool isEmpty()
    {
        return m_head == NULL;
    }

private:
    node_t* m_head;
    node_t* m_tail;
};
```

Also, I am returning a data from the private node, but in the get function, I`ll always return a copy variable that will be not initialized  if queue is empty, will it be  better to use new() and return a pointer or NULL if no head node is present?

Comment: You should always use either `malloc()`/`free()` or `new`/`delete`, do not mix them.

Comment: You also forgot to implement the destructor (hint: what should happen to the memory that was allocated if the queue itself is destroyed?)

Comment: I`ve fixed this, seems I've posted not exact same code as my IDE, my debugger finds a data in the m_tail element... Maybe my algorithm is wrong? After pull from head all, tail has a data.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing `malloc()` for the allocation with `delete` for the release. Doing so is undefined behavior.

With respect to the result of `get()` on an empty queue, I would make it a precondition for `get()` that the queue is non-empty.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I`ve just wrongly copy/paste it here, originally I am not mixing. Will edit it. I need a really simple solution, without the need to implement puts and gets with all kind of pinters, references and concrete variables. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same logic in R.Sadgewick's "Algorithms in C" however, he too is losing the tail data when emptying the queue. The code in the dequeue is deleting a classical linked list removing algorithm, but in the end the tail node still remains, I've just set head to tail to head.next to make sure the queue nodes are null in the end of the program.

```
template <typename T> class Queue
{
    struct node_t {
        T data;
        struct node_t* next;
    };

    node_t* new_node(T data, node_t* link)
    {
        node_t* n = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        if (n) {
            n->data = data;
            n->next = link;
        }
    }

public:
    Queue() : m_head(NULL), m_tail(NULL) {}
    ~Queue()
    {
        while (!isEmpty()) {
            T* n = dequeue();
        }
    }

    void enqueue(T data)
    {
        if (m_head == NULL) {
            m_tail = new_node(data, m_head);
            m_head = m_tail;
        } else {
            m_tail->next = new_node(data, m_tail->next);
            m_tail = m_tail->next;

        }
    }

    T* dequeue()
    {
        if (m_head == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }

        T t = m_head->data;
        node_t* n = m_head;
        // Sadgewick:
        // m_head = m_head->next;
        // mine:
        m_head = m_tail = m_head->next;
        free(n);
        return &t;
    }

    bool isEmpty()
    {
        return m_head == NULL;
    }

private:
    node_t* m_head;
    node_t* m_tail;
};
```